# InputDecoration in DropdownButtonFormField adds a padding on the right (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Apparently, when I add a prefixIcon to a InputDecoration in my DropdownButtonFormField, it adds a right padding that I don't know where it comes from.

[image]

My code:

```
Container(
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: CustomTheme.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: DropdownButtonFormField<dynamic>(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          prefixIcon: icon != null
              ? Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Icon(icon, color: CustomTheme.orange),
                )
              : null,
        ),
        isDense: true,
        iconEnabledColor: CustomTheme.orange,
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
        ),
        isExpanded: true,
        items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>>(
          (dynamic value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(
                value.name,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
                      color: CustomTheme.black,
                    ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
        onChanged: onChanged,
        value: dropdownValue,
      ),
    );
```

As a hot fix, I created a row in order to put the icon as a separate widget outside the DropdownButtonFormField, but I'd like to know if there's a way handle this with the InputDecoration widget (or a reason why this happens)

Comment: have you tried add/change
    `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),` and `isDense: true` 
inside InputDecoration( .. )

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution, just modifying the default values.